# Create table with independent cell measures

Tags: powerbi, visualization

I am new to any data visualization tool. I want to make a table like this:

| Metrics | Customer | Vendor | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Number of Brands | 5 | 4 | 9 |
| Number of Unique User Accounts | 4 | 2 | 6 |
| Daily Active User | 2 | 3 | 5 |

In the above table the header row and column are static while the values for Customer, Vendor, and Total are calculated from other tables.

Another place where I am having problem is that all the rows are independent of each other, but I don't know how can I apply queries to just the cells instead of the whole column.

1. I tried to create a table in Power BI and dynamically assign values. But this won't work as they values while creating `DATATABLE` needs to be static.
2. I tried to imitate how I would do it in excel i.e., create a measure for each cell and assign it to that cell. But I later learnt that I cannot assign measures to a particular cell.
3. I am currently trying something with `SWITCH` with the logic that I can pass some data to understand which cell it is from, and I can return a different measure accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `SWITCH` and `SELECTEDVALUE`. As shown below,

```
Customer = SWITCH(TRUE(),
    SELECTEDVALUE(Platform_Table[Metrics]) = "No. of Accounts", [c_1],
    SELECTEDVALUE(Platform_Table[Metrics]) = "No. of Users", [c_2],
    ...
    0
)
```

Then used the above measure as a column for the table. Did the same for Vendor and created a Total column.

Note: I had statically created table `Platform_Table` as I knew what I needed.